# How to recover accidentally deleted ID column from List?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, disaster-recovery, id

I accidentally deleted the ID from one of my Lists in Sharepoint Designer.  There was a Workflow dependent on that ID.  I think the ID must still be in the List, but I can no longer see it on any views of the List.

Comment: is your issue just in showing the ID column in your list views?

Comment: Also the workflow editor doesn't see the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

To show the ID column in your view,

- Open your list > select your view.
- From the above ribbon > click on Modify view.
- Beside column section > select the ID column and set its position.

[image]

- Now the ID column should be shown to your view.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the ID in no longer in the "Column Name" list, and so I cannot select it.

Comment: It's the first time I see this strange issue !! what's your SharePoint version?, Is it shown before? if yes so what you have done before it disappeared ?!

Comment: Same here, didn't know you could delete the ID column. Guess I've never tried.

Comment: Okay, the ID column is available and I can view it in SharePoint, but not SPD site columns or list columns. That is where I thought I deleted it. When I tried to add another column there as ID, it says there is already a column with that name but I can't see it. So now I'm not exactly sure what "broke" my workflow. I thought it was because it was pointing to Current:ID... but that must not be the issue.  I now have another problem, and will start a different thread.

Comment: The workflow will not stay in the SPD associated list. I publish it and it shows in the list, but if/when I refresh or get out of SPD, the list is gone. It doesn't show in SP workflow settings for that list. BTW using 2010 version.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you delete the column in SPD?  I just looked a list in SPD and the option to delete the ID column is grey-ed out.

Do you have access to PowerShell on one of your servers?

If so, try this:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://YOURsiteURL/"
$list = $web.GetList("Your List")
foreach($field in $list.fields)
{
    Write-Host $field.Title
}
```

This will output all the columns in your list/library.